# DHCP server on bridged Ethernet/Wifi not working; Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, bridge

I live in an apartment complex that provides Wifi. I have my Windows 7 laptop connected to this Wifi, and that works fine. I have setup a network bridge between Wifi and the Ethernet port. I have also installed the DHCP server from http://www.dhcpserver.de/.

I have connected a known good embedded Linux machine directly via an Ethernet cable to the laptop's Ethernet port. The problem is that the DHCP client on the Linux board is not getting an address from the DHCP server that should be running on the laptop. A screenshot of a Wireshark capture is shown below:

[image: 1]

Can anyone suggest what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When connecting your machine straight on to the Linux box, you need to ensure that the ethernet cable is a [cross over cable](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ethernet-crossover-cable/). You can **not** make use of a "normally" crimped cable for connecting machines directly.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but my embedded board definitely has an auto MIDX Ethernet port, so it was my understanding that these do not need a crossover cable?

Comment: Can you say the same from the linux box ethernet interface?

Comment: Maybe this is worth a shot.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/make-windows-7-act-as-a-dhcp-server/8ff345f2-99b5-4670-bb6f-32d7bb63de3c